# Understanding solr response format

Tags: solr

**EDIT ::** Figured it was worth trying to simplify my question.  What is $result[0] below?  Why is it returning the spellcheck term that I provided.

I setup a spellcheck requestHandler.  It seems like it is working properly but I don't understand the response...I'll provide all the config data below but to jump directly into the question here is the response for a spellcheck.q = 'gewürztramine' (expecting to find : Gewürztraminer)

```
Array
(
    [0] => gewürztramine
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [numFound] => 1
            [startOffset] => 0
            [endOffset] => 13
            [origFreq] => 0
            [suggestion] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [word] => gewürztraminer
                            [freq] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What is that first entry in the array?  It seems like I want $result[1]->suggestion[0]->word.  This position in the response doesn't make any sense to me.  Is there any logic to it?  Can i always find the top response in that exact position?

solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
 <lst name="defaults">
 <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
 <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
 <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
 <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
 <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
 <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
 </lst>
 <arr name="last-components">
 <str>spellcheck</str>
 </arr>
 </requestHandler>

<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
<!-- a spellchecker built from a field of the main index -->
<lst name="spellchecker">
<str name="name">default</str>
<str name="field">title</str>
<str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
<!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
<float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
<!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
<int name="minPrefix">1</int>
<!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
<int name="minQueryLength">3</int>
</lst>
</searchComponent>
```

schema.xml

```
   <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />


    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

REQUEST:

`http://xxx/solr/grape/spell?q=gew%C3%BCrztramine&wt=json&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.q=gew%C3%BCrztramine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is that first entry in the array?

`$result[1]->suggestion[0]->word` is the suggestion.

> Is there any logic to it?

Solr groups his response in different parts. In an abstract level, its someting like that:
* search restults
* spellchecking suggestion
* facetet search result
...

In your case, the suggestion work correctly, because you searched for `gewürztramine` and the suggestion is `gewürztraminer`

> Can i always find the top response in that exact position?

You will always find the top spell-checking suggestion for this word at this position.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't understand what $result[0] is.  Why is returning the query value that I sent it?

Comment: Because it may correct you on several words. So it is telling you which one this is a suggestion for. Try it with two misspelt words.

Comment: ok, doing two mispelt words help me understand.  Very strange format.  Instead of $suggestions[0] = term, $suggestions[1] = data, why not $suggestions[0]->term, added to the rest of information like $suggestions[0]->numFound, $suggestions[0]->startOffset.